# How to use javascript to detect GPS and WIFI of mobile on/off?

Tags: javascript, gps

I am writing a website for smartphone.
I use javascript: **navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition** to get location.

Nevertheless, I need to detect the GPS (and Wifi) on or off before do this functions.
I have searched but I did not see any way to detect the GPS (and Wifi) on or off.

Please help me how to detect it **by javascript or jquery**?
Thanks

Comment: I don't think all smartphones have a concept of "GPS" or "Wi-Fi". It seems outside of the scope of Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with just Javascript. 
You need to look into a framework like [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/).

Phonegap let's you build mobile-apps using just javascript, and provides ways to do the things you ask.

If you want just a normal *website* (not an app) to do that, then from what I know, it is just not possible at the moment.